Number of homomorphisms between $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}/(pq)\Bbb{Z}$
While calculating number of homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$, I found that by fixing $\phi$, a homomorphism such that $\phi(0)=0$ and $\phi(1) = x \pmod{17}$, it is possible to generate the entire set $Im(\phi)$. Then, we have $17$ choices for $x$, hence the number of homomorphisms I calculated as $17$. For given primes $p$ and $q$, number of homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ is $q$ by similar logic. Now, the reason we can apply this logic is because $p$ and $q$ are co-prime. However, in the case of calculating number of homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ I am stuck. I feel I cannot apply this logic, since $gcd(p,pq)=p$.
Please help.
Edit: Thanks to @Arturo Magidin, I observed that the previous assertion is indeed incorrect. We have only the trivial homomorphism if $(p,q) = 1$. But I am still not sure how to calculate it for counting number of homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}/pq\Bbb{Z}$

A cyclic group of order $n$ contains one and only one subgroup of order $d$ when $d\mid n$ (and no subgroups of order $d$ when $d\nmid n$).

Your assertion about $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$ is incorrect. While a priori there are $17$ possible choices for where to send a $1$, not every such choice will give a homomorphism. For example, say you want to send $1\in\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ to $1\in\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$. Then you would need to send $2$ to $2$, $3$ to $3$, $4$ to $4$. But then you would have that while $\phi(0) = \phi(1+4)$, you have $\phi(1)+\phi(4) = 1+4 = 5\not\equiv 0\pmod{17}$. So this function is not a homomorphism.
